# WKWebview shows text with padding

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using a `WKWebView` which has the width of the entire screen.
I'm getting this text from google docs into that `WKWebView` -

[image]

The text should stretch from side to side. Why am I getting this large padding from both sides?

Answer (score 0):

First, check by debugging view hierarchy, make sure WKWebView is not having any padding.
you can debug in safari, to find out is there any CSS that is causing this padding.